# Send imagem to Email - PHP

Tags: php, html, file, email, session

I am developing a system that performs sending mail, but when you send an image through the field input file, it ends up not returning anything in the mailbox.
Can someone help me?

I searched in several places, but was unsuccessful, When the email is sent the file part of the image arrives empty.

> HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<meta name="viewport" content="width:500", initial-scale=1>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Enviar Mensagens</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>

<!--FORMULARIO-->
<div id="formulario">
<form method="POST" action="enviando.php"   enctype="multipart/form-data">
<center><img src="../imagem/logo_XXX.png" widht="80" height="60"/></center>
<legend>ENVIAR MENSAGEM</legend>
<span>Nome</span>
<input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome:" required/><br>
<span>Email</span>
<input type="email" name="email1" placeholder="Email:" required/><br>

<span>Assunto</span>
<select name="assunto" required>
<option value="Aviso">Aviso</option>
<option value="Dúvida">Dúvida</option>
<option value="Urgente">Urgente</option>
<option value="Boleto">Boleto</option>
<option value="Pagamento Atrasado">Pagamento Atrasado</option>
<option value="Parabéns">Parabéns</option>  
<option value="Reclamação">Reclamação</option>  
</select><br>

<span>Arquivo</span>
<input type="file" name="arquivo"><br/><br/>
<span>Mensagem</span>
<textarea name="texto" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
<input type="hidden" name="acao" value="Enviar">
<input type="submit" value="enviar" class="btn"/>
</form>
</div>

<span><center>
<font color="#fff">&copy; <?php echo date('Y');?>xxx Todos os direitos reservados</font>
</center></span>

<div id="footer">
<div style="clear:both;">
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

> PHP

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("conexao/config.php");


$ti;
$ti= $_SESSION['email']; 


$nome=$_POST['nome'];
$email=$_POST['email1'];
$assunto=$_POST['assunto'];
$arquivo= $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['arquivo']['arquivo']);
$mensagem=$_POST['texto'];

 /* HERE RETURN VOID IN FILE IMAGE */
$to="contato@silvaplataformas.com.br";
$subject="$assunto";
$mensagem="
<strong>Nome:</strong>
$nome<br><br>
<strong>Email:</strong>
$email<br><br>
<strong>Assunto:</strong> 
$assunto<br><br>
<strong>Arquivo:</strong> 
$arquivo<br><br>
<strong>Mensagem:</strong>
$mensagem<br><br>";

$header="MIME-version:1.0\n";
$header.="Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
$header.="From: $email\n";

mail($to, $subject, $mensagem, $header);
if(mail==true){
header("Location: sucesso.php");
}else{
header("Location: erro.php");
} 
?>
```

> can anybody help me?

Comment: `basename($_FILES['arquivo']['arquivo'])` is incorrect. You also have a typo in `widht`. The word is spelled "width".

Comment: thanks Func Forty, what would be the correct way to apply?

Answer (score -3):

instead of

```
mail($to, $subject, $mensagem, $header);
if(mail==true){
header("Location: sucesso.php");
}else{
header("Location: erro.php");
```

use

```
$location = mail($to, $subject, $mensagem, $header) ? "sucesso.php" : "erro.php";
header("location: " . $location);
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip .
 How could I upload with the image?

Comment: In your original code you did not check the return value from mail() function. I used ternary operator ? to select appropriate redirection page and ther put it into header() for redirection. That's all. Why I got negative marks!? Who knows. For file upload there's a lot examples online. You have to send via POST `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and use `$_FILES` variable to use it.